# Looking for a way to override the GetResponseStream Method of HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, stream, httpwebresponse

I am looking for a way to override the GetResponseStream method of HttpWebResponse class, in order to have a custom stream returned. Essentially my goal is to modify the stream. Not sure if that is possible? This is being done in the context of integrating with a web service and i need to strip away some of the content from the response stream. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, I don't believe that's possible. It's very unclear what your architecture is though - can't you wrap the web service in an API which does the right thing? Do you really need to expose the raw stream anyway?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to web service and it cannot be modified.

Comment: No, I was talking about doing it at the *client* side. You really haven't given us much context here...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Actually, you can use _deeply_ evil hacks to do this; I tried it once and succeeded.  (register a custom protocol handler for your domain name, and call the obsolete serialization ctor)

Comment: @SLaks: I'm hoping the OP is looking for something which isn't deeply evil :)

Comment: something similar is mentioned here, but its not stated on exactly how to override the getresponsestream method
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011823/soaphttpclientprotocol-get-response-as-a-stream-instead-of-a-string

Comment: @Bukhatir: Again: How are you _consuming_ the webservice?

Comment: using WSE 3.0 (proxy generated by VS), i know i will be asked to go wcf route but thats not an option :(

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to override the GetResponseStream method of
>   HttpWebResponse class, in order to have a custom stream returned.

Cool. The [`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) is virtual anyways, so go ahead, override it and return whatever you want. Of course you will have to design your code in such a manner so that you are not working with concrete implementations of the HttpWebResponse class which is seldom the case. Coz you usually you get an HttpWebResponse instance from an HttpWebRequest. So that's tight coupling. So start thinking about how you could abstract that entire HTTP stuff in your code. I mean stop thinking in terms of HttpWebRequests. Start thinking in terms of interfaces and abstractions in your code. That's what's gonna save you anyways and that's what's gonna weaken the coupling between the different layers of your code and make it unit testable.

The point of this answer is that your code should be designed in such a way so that it doesn't depend on any HttpWebRequest concrete classes. You should start thinking in terms of hiding this behind an interface abstraction that you could easily mock in your unit test.

Once you abstract your web service call behind an interface you could very easily mock this call in your unit test to test the actual behavior of the system without relying on specific classes in your test.

Comment: But that requires creating a subclass of `HttpWebResponse` to start with... whereas the instance is normally created by the guts of the framework (in `WebRequest.GetResponse` etc). Can you give an example of how you'd override it *and use it*? (Maybe there's a plugin mechanism that I've never had cause to use before...)

Comment: Yeah, that's what it requires. That's why you shouldn't be relying on any specific HTTP context stuff such as HttpWebRequests in the code. And no, I'm never gonna override the GetResponseStream methods anyways. That would have been completely insane. I would have hidden the entire dependency on the HttpWebrequest stuff behind an interface abstraction that I could have more than happily mocked in my unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily override `HttpWebResponse`'s behavior. Either you wrap the web-service API on the client side, as @Jon suggested in the comment, or, if you really want to get adventurous, change the *request*, pointing it to a proxy server that will modify the stream as required.

It's not going to be trivial, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can modify the code calling GetResponseStream, the Adapter pattern might not be a bad choice.

class MyCustomStream : Stream 
{
      Stream originalStream;

```
  MyCustomStream(Stream originalStream) 
  { this.originalStream = originalStream; }

  override int Read(byte [] buffer, int offset, int count) 
  {
      byte [] temp = new byte[count];
      var ret = originalStream.Read(temp, offset, count);
      // modify your buffer if desired
      Array.Copy(buffer, temp);
      return ret;
  }

  // implement all the other abstract methods of Stream and just call originalStream
```

}

// now replace code like this....

var myStream = request.GetResponseStream();

// with....

var myStream = new MyCustomStream(request.GetResponseStream());

Comment: This will probably not work for my case. Its a java web service that I am consuming through .net and its sending a bit of content that actually fails on the client side. 

I have already created a subclass out of the original proxy and overriden the GetWebResponse method and within this method I actually need to alter the stream's content so that when it is actually parsed it does not raise an exception. Hope you get the point

Comment: Not sure I do...if you alter it at the stream level that would be before anything is parsed, right?

Comment: yup thats the case. if i can just alter it at the point it will work. The parsing to follow will not fail.

Comment: So, if you wrap the stream like I showed you (assuming you can modify the code calling GetResponseStream), you can change the contents of the buffer at the comment point "// modify your buffer if desired" That will change the the content of the stream from the callers perspective and you would have ultimate control over what the caller receives.

Comment: In this case the wrapper method around GetResponseStream method is GetWebResponse method, which I can override, so in a way I have access to the code calling GetResponseStream method. But the problem here is that the webresponse returned here will still be holding the original stream and again when deserialized/parsed that will result into exception.